# How to change Bing Map code to Google Map code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dynamics-crm-2011, bing-maps

Good day,

Does anyone have an idea of how to change a bing map to google map api code. I have found a very useful code on line that is coded using bing maps and would like to change it to work with google maps. if found the code here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/01/19/custom-charting-capabilities-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx

Code below:

```
<html>

   <head>

   <title>Accounts on Bing Maps</title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

   var map;
   // Function to construct key-value pairs from a query string.
   function getParametersFromQuery(query) {
   var parametersDictionary = new Array();

   var parameters = query.split('&');

   for (var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {

   var keyAndValue = parameters[i].split('=');

   parametersDictionary[unescape(keyAndValue[0])] = unescape(keyAndValue[1]);

   }

   return parametersDictionary;

   }

   // Function that makes a GET request to the CRM REST end-point, and invokes a callback with the results.
   function retrieveFromCrmRestApi(url, callback) {

   $.ajax({
   type: "GET",

   url: GetGlobalContext().getServerUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc" + url,

   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

   dataType: "json",

   success: function (data) {

   callback(data.d);

   }
   });

   }


   // Function that retrieves the corresponding CRM chart, and invokes the callback when successful.
   function loadChartFromCrm(callback) {

   var parameters = getParametersFromQuery(window.location.search.substring(1));
   parameters = getParametersFromQuery(parameters["data"]);

   var id = parameters["visid"].substr(1, 36);

   var type = parameters["vistype"];

   var url = (type == "1111" ? "/SavedQueryVisualizationSet" : "/UserQueryVisualizationSet")

    + "(guid'" + id + "')?$select=DataDescription,PresentationDescription";
   retrieveFromCrmRestApi(url, callback);

   }



   var locations = new Array();
   function plotAccountLocations(accounts) {
   if (accounts.length > 0) {

   var account = accounts.pop();

   var address = account.Address1_City + ', ' + account.Address1_Country;

   map.Find(null, address, null, null, 0, 1, false, false, false, false,

   function (shapeLayer, results, places, moreResults, error) {

   if (null != places && places.length > 0) {

   var place = places[0];

   var newShape = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Pushpin, place.LatLong);

   newShape.SetTitle(account.Name);

   newShape.SetDescription(address);

   locations.push(newShape);
   }

   // When we have found (or not found) the current account,

   // recursively call the same function to find the next one.

   plotAccountLocations(accounts);

   });

   }

   else {

   var shapeLayer = new VEShapeLayer();

   map.AddShapeLayer(shapeLayer);

   shapeLayer.AddShape(locations);

   }

   }



   function loadAccountsFromCrm(dataDescription) {

   var url = "/AccountSet?$select=Address1_Country,Address1_City,Name";

   if (null != dataDescription) {

   // Filter accounts based on country specified in data description.

   url += "&$filter=Address1_Country eq '" + dataDescription + "'";

   }

   retrieveFromCrmRestApi(url,

   function (data) {

   var results = data["results"];

   var accounts = new Array();

   for (resultKey in results) {

   accounts.push(results[resultKey]);

   }

   // Once accounts are retrieved from CRM Server, plot their locations on map.

   plotAccountLocations(accounts);

   }
   );
   }



   function getMap(presentationDescription) {

   // Set center and zoom defaults.

   var center = null;

   var zoom = 4;

   if (null != presentationDescription) {

   // Calculate map-center and zoom from the presentation description.

   var arguments = presentationDescription.split(',');

   if (arguments.length > 1) {

   center = new VELatLong(arguments[0], arguments[1]);

   }

   if (arguments.length > 2) {

   zoom = arguments[2];

   }

   }

   map = new VEMap("map");

   map.LoadMap(center, zoom, VEMapStyle.Road, true, VEMapMode.Mode2D, false, 0);

window.onresize = function (event) { map.Resize(document.body.clientWidth, document.body.clientHeight); };

   window.onresize(null);

   }



   function loadMap() {

   // First, get the chart object from CRM Server.

   loadChartFromCrm(
   function (chart) {

   // Once we have retrieved the chart, format the map based on the chart's presentation description.

   getMap(chart.PresentationDescription);

   // Get Accounts from CRM Server based on the chart's data description, and plot them on the map.

   loadAccountsFromCrm(chart.DataDescription);

   }

   );

   }

   </script>

   </head>

   <body onload="loadMap()">

   <div id="map"></div>

   </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: Have a look at [Google chart with maps](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map#Example)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy out of the box solution for what you are looking for.

Google API has many differences. For example, the Google API leaves keeping track of map children to the programmer (you).  There is no means of looping through the map controls like there is with the Bing API.  This means that your solution for saving the map content and re-displaying it will be a little different.

Although, since both API's are done via javascript, all you need to do is convert your functionality according to their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference);

- [Geocoding Sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)
- [Simple Map Initialization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)
- [Adding Shapes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple)
- [Adding Markers (pushpin)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)